# SQL: Fetch additional column without adding in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a query:

```
SELECT
    asset_ref_id,
    MAX(updated_at),
    people_id
FROM
    asset_aud
WHERE
    revtype = 2
    AND updated_at BETWEEN TO_DATE('2020-05-20T10:09:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE('2020-05-24T10:18:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'
    )
GROUP BY
    asset_ref_id,
    people_id
```

I also want to fetch `id` column from `asset_aud` table in the resultset. But I do not want to add it in `groupby` , because it will then add a group condition w.r.t to `id` column.

So how can fetch `id` column as well without inflating the resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregation column:

```
min(asset_aud.id)
```

or perhaps:

```
listagg(asset_aud.id, ',') within group (order by asset_aud.id)
```